# Python Class update parent variables by subclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance, properties, subclass

With my limited understanding of `@property`,`@setter`, and `@getter`, I came up with following code.

```
class BitCounts:
    sign_bit = 0
    exponent_bits = 0
    mantissa_bits = 0
    _total_bits = 0

    @property
    def total_bits(self):
        return self._total_bits

    @total_bits.setter
    def total_bits(self):
        self._total_bits = self.sign_bit + self.exponent_bits + self.mantissa_bits


class Single(BitCounts):
    sign_bit = 1
    offset = 0x7F
    exponent_bits = 8
    mantissa_bits = 23
    _total_bits = BitCounts.total_bits


class Double(BitCounts):
    sign_bit = 1
    offset = 0x400
    exponent_bits = 11
    mantissa_bits = 52
    _total_bits = BitCounts.total_bits
```

My intention is to use the subclass `Single` and `Double` in other functions as a set of options like so, for example:

```
    def some_function(option=Single):
        print("exponent bit counts are: %d", option.exponent_bits)
        print("mantissa bit counts are: %d", option.mantissa_bits)
        print("total bit counts are: %d", option.total_bits)
```

I would like `total_bits` to be automatically recalculated using values from subclass `Single` or `Double`.

I am trying to avoid extra functions to perform the calculation at subclass level.

With above codes, by calling `Single.total_bits`, or `Double.total_bits`, I am only getting a message saying `<property object at 0x000002258DF7CB30>`, what did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using subclasses with hard-coded static values suggests these should be *instances* not subclasses. This is also suggested by your temptation to use `self` even though you haven't made any instances. `self` refers to a particular instance.

Also, setters typically take a value as an argument. You don't have that in your setter because total_bits is completely dependent on other values. As such you should just move your setter calculation to the getter and return the result of the calculation.

Consider:

```
class BitCounts:
    def __init__(self, sign,offset, exponent, mantissa):       
        self.sign_bit = sign
        self.offset = offset
        self.exponent_bits = exponent
        self.mantissa_bits = mantissa

    @property
    def total_bits(self):
        return self.sign_bit + self.exponent_bits + self.mantissa_bits

# now make two instances:
single = BitCounts(1, 0x7F, 8, 23 )
double = BitCounts(1, 0x400, 11, 52)

print(single.total_bits)
# 32

print(double.total_bits)
# 64
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot, however, I noticed that by using `@property`, each time `single.total_bits` is called, it will perform recalculation. Is there a way to avoid that because it can get expensive with complicated calculations with multiple calls to `single or double.total_bits`.

Comment: @user97662 you could cache it, but you would need to update the cache when any of the dependent variables (like `sign_bit`) changed. That's only a problem if those values might change. If those values never change, you can set the value once as a regular instance variable inside `__init__`.  with `self.total_bits = self.sign_bit + self.exponent_bits + self.mantissa_bits`. Then you don't need a getter at all.  Careful of premature optimization thought. Addition is cheap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
class Single(BitCounts):
    sign_bit = 1
    offset = 0x7F
    exponent_bits = 8
    mantissa_bits = 23
    _total_bits = BitCounts.total_bits

    def get_total_bits(self):
        # Update values here, example below
        self._total_bits = self._total_bits + 1
        return self._total_bits
```

Then call:

```
option = Single()
option.get_total_bits()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to call an instance method from a class.

```
class A:
  @property
  def foo(self):
    return 1

print(A.foo) # prints an object of function "foo"
print(A().foo) # prints "1"
```

To accomplish this, at least from my knowledge you need to use a metaclass similar to what they do here: [Per-class @property decorator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621241/per-class-property-decorator-in-python)